# Getting javac to work in the PATH environment variable

Tags: java, windows, path, javac, environment

So I've downloaded the latest JDK and installed it.
I'm starting to go through a textbook with some tutorials but in no part of the textbook do they tell you how to 'setup' the javac compiler. If I type 'javac' into the command line it simply says it is not a recognised command. I have added the path of the bin folder to the path environment variable but it still says not a recognised command. Please help!!

Comment: I started writing quite a detailed answer to this http://codecubed.wordpress.com/

Comment: Presumably you amended the PATH via the control panel. Did you start a brand new cmd window after the edit?

Comment: So you must have messed up your PATH somehow - setting the PATH is usually the only thing to "install" JDK

Comment: To test if your path is wrong, just navigate to your Java `/bin` folder and try running a java command.  If it works, it's your path, if not, it's your installation...most likely

Answer (score 0):

- Check if running `javac` works from within its folder.
- `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and make sure it points to the right folder.
- `echo %PATH%` and make sure it includes the right path.

Comment: `echo` is the windows print command but the environmental variables are output with `%JAVA_HOME%`

Answer (score 0):

try to use the direct path to the javac like c:/swd/jdk/

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to modify PATH variable through command `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\java\` ? If so, the PATH variable is not permanently stored yet. Use `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\path\to\java\"` instead, and check if it was added by `echo %PATH%`, and check again in new cmd window. I had almost the same problem; I don't know the difference between set and setx, but the former didn't work for me, too :).

Answer (score 0):

Javac is sitting in the bin directory contained in the area where your java compiler and interpreter were installed. So, assuming the path to bin is C:.....\bin, type set path=%path%;C:.....\bin at the command prompt.